# EditText to Input Money Amount

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I am developing a Point Of Sales app.

So I would like to let user to enter the purchase amount

1. Let's say User input `100000` but I want it to automatically show up `100,000`. and `1000000` become `1,000,000`
2. The second problem is that, I don't want user to be able to input `.` themselves.
3. Third problem is that since this is money, we can't let user to enter 0 in the beginning.

Any ideas?

So far I can only come up with `inputType=numberDecimal` which is not really helpful.

Thank you very much

***P.S.: I do not need any decimal places***

Comment: what if user want to input 10000, you will make it 100?

Comment: for your second problem you can specify digits for edittext by using digits keyword in edittext xml

Comment: for your third problem you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490054/android-the-first-digit-in-the-edit-text-can-not-be-zero

Comment: and for your first problem you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem follow this link
[Thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext)

For your second problem
add this to your editext

```
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

And for your third problem you have to use TextWatcher like this

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (editText1.getText().toString().matches("^0") )
        {
            // Not allowed
            Toast.makeText(context, "not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editText1.setText("");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
});
```

Comment: But, unluckily user is able to input 0000s in the prefix of the amount, once he has something in the EditText.

Answer (score 4):

if you want use in currency  add `addTextChangedListener` to your desired edittext then monitor changes and reformat it , here is sample code

```
private String current = "";
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
       [your_edittext].removeTextChangedListener(this);

       String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

       double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
       String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

       current = formatted;
       [your_edittext].setText(formatted);
       [your_edittext].setSelection(formatted.length());

       [your_edittext].addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand - why do you need last string '[your_edittext].addTextChangedListener(this);' for?

Comment: you need to de-attach the listener to formate the string cause if you don't it will keep firing and after you finish re-attach the listener  again

Answer (score 1):

You could implement one or more [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)s to enforce those constraints on your `EditText`. It is possible to attach multiple filters on an `EditText` by using it's `setFilters` method.

You could also use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)s to achieve the same thing. However, using `InputFilter` makes a little bit more sense as it allows you to alter the text without having to call the `setText` method after each change you make in the input.